# What column character encoding should I use for password_hash()?

Tags: php, mysql

What column character encoding should I use for storing a password generated with password_hash() of PHP in a MySQL database?

Comment: If it's a web app - just go with UTF-8 all the way through from the front to the database for everything... it'll save you a  lot of headaches down the line; `password_hash()` will give you a hash value anyway.

Comment: @CD001 yes I store everything in utf8, but I'm not sure if it is necessary for password_hash().

Comment: With current hash values it *shouldn't* make any difference - they're all simple alphanumerics... but there's no good reason to juggle the charset for password AFAICT; just stick with UTF-8 ... (*general ci* should be fine with MySQL)

Comment: Tell MySQL to use `VARCHAR(255)` with `utf8mb4` and it will throw an error when you want to create an `UNIQUE` index. PHP does not specify an encoding for [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), it does say *"255 characters would be a good choice"*. So the best choice is `VARBINARY(255)`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The best way to go is UTF-8.

Although currently password hash returns values in latin1 charset, with utf-8 you are future proof. You cannot know how things will evolve in the future with PHP, hashing etc

Comment: Ye-es except if you're changing to a new hashing algorithm at some undefined point in the future everyone will have to reset their passwords anyway so you can update the way the data is stored in that field then... so, practically, it'll not really matter.

Comment: So when not if. So future proof lasts x months

Comment: @CD001 - PHP's Password API is designed to deal transparently with a change of algorithm. If used correctly, you would specify `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` as the algorithm, which would cause it to use the one preferred by the currently running PHP version. However, passwords hashed with an older algorithm will be picked up and accepted, but will return `true` on the `password_needs_rehash()` function, allowing you to save an updated hash for affected users when they next log in. So no, you don't have to reset their passwords. (although if the algorithm is compromised you may still want to do so anyway)

Comment: Obviously nothing is future proof in the true sense of the term. 

You will simply have to worry for one less thing. I wrote it in that sense. 

I don't know if you have been in a messy situation with thousands of inaccessible accounts in your carrer. I have been and even the least burden taken off my back was really welcome ...

Comment: @Simba good point - I was kinda working on the assumption that the hashing type was being specified... because reasons :)

Comment: Also use the `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` collation, to allow for multiple hashes per account... or implement things properly and use `VARBINARY(255)` for strict comparison and let PHP deal with its default encoding.

Answer (score 1):

I question whether password hash should even be in core. It certainly addresses some problems faced by underworld implementations. It dummies down security by marrying security to php release. But at least you get something. And afterall, the PHP community has shall we say high standard deviation of talent.

Comment: When a widely distributed platform like Magento still uses MD5 (granted salted MD5) for passwords... I think it probably does more good than harm rolling a password hashing function into the core.

Comment: Opium for the masses. Like I said.